# OrmLite superfluous fields creating

Tags: android, field, ormlite

I use that class for table creation:

```
public class Category {
    public final static String CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME  = "title";
    @SerializedName("id")
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    int id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME)
    String title;

    // need for ORMlite
    public Category() {}

    public Category (int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

And get such message as:

> 08-01 11:28:17.269: I/TableUtils(26960): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `levels` (`title` VARCHAR , `id` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )

Is it about that in my table are 3 fields? Or there 2 fields  - 'title' and 'id'...If there are 3 fields tell me why please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it about that in my table are 3 fields? Or there 2 fields - 'title' and 'id'...If there are 3 fields tell me why please..

I assume you are talking about the generated SQL:

> CREATE TABLE levels (title VARCHAR , id INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (id) )

There are *not* 3 fields being defined there.  There are 2 fields (`title` and `id`) and a `PRIMARY KEY` designation which is for Sqlite.  Sqlite uses the `PRIMARY KEY` SQL to define which field should be indexed as the identifier for the row.  See the [Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it about that in my table are 3 fields?

Your table has two columns, what would make you think there are 3 columns?
If you analyze the sql statement:

> CREATE TABLE levels (title VARCHAR , id INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (id) )

you will observe there are two columns, `title`  and `id` (which is also the primary key).

If you need another answer please rephrase your question.

Comment: Are you confusing rows and columns @dadu?  You use the word row in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I get such a message

```
 08-01 11:28:17.269: I/TableUtils(26960): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE levels (title VARCHAR , id INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (id) )
```

, it means of 2 columns creation, not 3. Thanks to [Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray)

Comment: I don't see how this helps at all for posterity and seems to be a duplicate of my information.  I'd remove it.